# Parallelization of merge by row.names of two large matrices

Tags: r, merge, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am trying to merge two large matrices by `row.names` in R with `merge`, but it's taking quite some time. Is there a possibility to parallelize the `merge` method? Maybe somehow with `foreach` library? Or maybe there are faster solutions that do the job?

I have 8 cores and 24 GB of RAM. Both matrices are about 1.4 Gb and consist of ~900 rows and ~22000 columns.

Here is the code to reproduce a small example of my data set:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, row.names = c('r1', 'r2', 'r3'))
df2 <- data.frame(z = 5:7, row.names = c('r1', 'r3', 'r7'))
dfMerged <- merge(df1, df2, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)
dfMerged[is.na(dfMerged)] <- 0
```

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but `data.table` might be quite a bit faster for something like this (as opposed to `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

This same merge should be faster in `data.table`.  I think it should be doable in parallel as well, but it might get more complicated.  Here is the same merge in `data.table`.

```
#Create data.table objects
dt1 <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, var=c('r1', 'r2', 'r3'))
dt2 <- data.table(z = 5:7, var = c('r1', 'r3', 'r7'))

#Set merge keys
setkey(dt1,var)
setkey(dt2,var)

#Perform full outer join
dtMerged <- merge(dt1,dt2,all=T)

#Replace NAs with zeros (edited for more efficient answer suggest by Arun)
for (j in c("x", "y", "z")) 
  set(dtMerged, i=which(is.na(dtMerged[[j]])), j=j, value=0L)
dtMerged

var x y z
1:  r1 1 1 5
2:  r2 2 2 0
3:  r3 3 3 6
4:  r7 0 0 7
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that in this case (scanning all columns). Would this be faster than ``dtMerged[,lapply(.SD,FUN=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),0,x))]``?